# Regex in powershell

Tags: powershell, regex

Im trying to use powershell to match the username and user status in the below:

```
Internal user ID:        1     Login name: ADMINISTRATOR    
Last login:
Last update user ID:     2     Date and time created: Tue Oct-25-2016 10:59:31
User status:             ENABLED       Reason for last status change:          0
```

With my regex builder I've got working:

`Login name:\s+(\w+)\n.*\n.*\nUser status:\s+(ENABLED|DISABLED)`

but when I use this in select-string its not returning anything. Anything obvious im doing wrong?

powershell:

```
$as = select-string "c:\users\ssfors\desktop\audit\user.rep" -pattern "Login name:\s+(\w+)\n.*\n.*\nUser status:\s+(ENABLED|DISABLED)"
foreach ($a in $as) {
echo $a.matches.groups[1].Value
}
```

Comment: Did you try to exclusively set the `-Path` parameter? In addition I'm not sure if PowerShell would match in single line mode by default. You could either try to remove line breaks with a simple replace or use a more complex RegEx statement/command that allows for single line mode matching.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at the following question you will see a way to get PowerShell/`Select-String` to use single line mode: [Multiline regex to match config block](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12572164/multiline-regex-to-match-config-block)

The problem you're facing is that by default a RegEx is usually applied per line of input. So your RegEx is only working on the first line that has `Internal user ID` and `Login name`.

What you need to do is to either remove the line breaks from your input or tell `Select-String` to use single line mode. In both cases you should adjust your RegEx to not use `\n` as it won't be needed. You could do it like this:

```
Login name:\s+(\w+)\s+.*?User status:\s+(ENABLED|DISABLED)
```

After this you either need adjust your input by e.g. running `` -replace '`n' `` (notice as well that you should be using `` `n `` within PowerShell) or you could use a modifier on the the input like stated in the question above. Your RegEx would change in that case to:

```
(?s)Login name:\s+(\w+)\s+.*?User status:\s+(ENABLED|DISABLED)
```

Even after all that you're not going to be finished just yet, `Select-String` actually returns line for line of an input if you supply `-Path`, so it's a good idea to read the whole file at once beforehand.

An example could be the following:

```
$fileContent = (Get-Content c:\users\ssfors\desktop\audit\user.rep) -join ''
$results = $fileContent | Select-String -pattern "Login name:\s+(\w+)\s+.*?User status:\s+(ENABLED|DISABLED)" -AllMatches
foreach($match in $results.Matches){
    foreach($group in $match.Groups){
        echo $group.Value
    }
}

if($results.Matches.Count -eq 1 -and $results.Matches[0].Groups.Count -eq 3){
    echo "User Name:", $results.Matches[0].Groups[1].Value;
    echo "Status:",  $results.Matches[0].Groups[2].Value;
}
```

Notice that the example doesn't use the single line modifier because it's not needed. It's reading the file and concatenating the lines using nothing as a delimiter.

Comment: Thank you very much for this! Answered my question perfectly.

Comment: Consider checking out [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://superuser.com/help/someone-answers). It's always nice to get a thank you but if it really did answer your question, consider marking it as the answer. Mere thank you posts are somewhat discouraged on this platform. :-)

Comment: Ok have done that, thanks again. The file that improcessing is about 40k lines, I think I'm running into a problem with the single lines size, and only getting the first 1/4 of users. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Don't process such a huge file, that would be the easy way. What size does that file have? Does it fit into RAM?

Comment: 2748kb, its the user file for an app, Im trying to select all the enabled user accounts for audit. But no your right $fileConent only reads in the first 1/4.

Comment: its only reading the first 3760 lines

Comment: This might warrant it's own question. Supply the code you got working so far. If you look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/140468/what-is-the-maximum-possible-length-of-a-net-string) it doesn't look like you should be hitting a length limit. You might be hitting some other kind of problem. Does the file have any kind of underlying semantics? You might be able to read chunks of it?

Comment: Ok I only have this issue on my laptop, not sure why but desktop runs through the whole file! Thank you again.